# Log person who deleted message in Discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm logging deleted Discord messages using the `on_message_delete` event like so:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            channel = db.field("SELECT LogID FROM guilds WHERE GuildID = ?", message.guild.id)

            if channel != 0: #If this guild wants to log deleted messages

                embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Deleted",
                                      color=discord.Color.red(),
                                      timestamp=getTime())
                embed.add_field(name="Member: ", value=message.author.mention, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name="Deleter: ", value="What do I put here", inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {message.author.id}")
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.author.avatar_url)
                fields = [("Message:", message.content, True),
                          ("Channel:", message.channel.mention, False)]

                for name, value, inline in fields:
                    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

                await self.bot.get_channel(channel).send(embed=embed)
```

Is there a way to get the id of a person who deleted a message so that even if a mod deletes someone else's message, you could still get their id?

(I have looked at other sources as well like this Reddit **[page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/ksiy7d/get_id_of_user_who_deleted_a_message_with_discord/)**, and the **[API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#message)** for messages but neither gave any insight)

Comment: you would have to use the discord [audit log](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=audit#audit-log-data) which is a nightmare

Comment: I'll look into it then ig

Comment: Audit logs would be your answer. But I have no clue how to get access to audit logs with discord.py lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to log them given @yotam rec's comment about using **[Discord Audit Logs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=audit#audit-log-data)**.

I did it by:

1. Reusing my `on_message_delete` listener

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
```

2. Creating a Boolean variable to ensure that I won't post the same embed twice

```py
modDeleted = False
```

3. Checking if a message delete audit log event was filed at the same time as this function

```
async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
    if entry.created_at.now(timezone("US/Eastern")) == getTime(): #Custom time function
        modDeleted = True
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Deleted By Mod")
        embed.add_field(name="Member: ", value = message.author.mention, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name = "Mod: ", value = entry.user.mention, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name = "Message: ", value = message.content, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name = "Channel: ", value = message.channel.mention, inline=False)

        await self.bot.get_channel(channel).send(embed=embed)
```

4. Checking if it couldn't find it in the audit log, and if it didn't, created another embed knowing that a user deleted their *own* message

```
if modDeleted == False:

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Deleted")
    embed.add_field(name="Member: ", value=message.author.mention, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Message: ", value=message.content, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Channel: ", value=message.channel.mention, inline=False)

    await self.bot.get_channel(channel).send(embed=embed)
```

Hope this helps anyone else having trouble with this as well!